# Could have already been vs. could have been... already

Tags: adverb-placement

Let's say you have watched a footage about aliens. It was compelling, but you don't believe that it was a real video of aliens, and you say:

> Nah, if that is true, it could have **already** been on the news.

Or

> Nah, if that is true, it could have been on the news **already**.

Are they both correct as for the **placement of adverbs.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some grammar rules about the placement of adverbs (since some placements are wrong), but you normally have several options.

> I have **already** done my homework
>
> I **already** have done my homework
>
> I have done my homework **already**.

Plus this one, which is not necessarily incorrect, but awkward out of context:

> **Already** I have done my homework

Anywhere else in the sentence doesn't work.  Otherwise, good style suggests you place the adverb as close as possible to the verb it modifies, but this depends on the context and personal preference.

Side note:  I don't think "could" is the right word for this context, since it's a hypothetical, and not a statement of ability.

> Nah, if that is true, it **would/should** have already been on the news.