# Have Already Been Learning or Have Been Already Learning

Tags: word-order

Which sentence is correct?

1. By 2030, I will have already been studying English for seven years.
2. By 2030, I will already have been studying English for seven years.

Comment: [This is related](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/187839/could-have-already-been-vs-could-have-been-already) and possibly a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, but since you want to emphasize seven years of studying English, it is more correct in this case to say `I will already have been`.

Answer (score -1):

'already' is an adverb and, basically, could be put to any places but adverbs, especially adverbs of frequency, in general, are put after modal verbs(like can, could, will, would, shall, should, may, might, must) and also after helping verbs like(do, be, have) and **before** main verbs.
In case of present perfect, the adverb is usualy also put between have/has and pp.

ex) All the guests have already arrived.

But remember that the 'adverb' can come before the thing that is modified by the 'adverb'. It's due to the fact that 'adverb'  itself is not a core element in a sentence.

By 2030, I will have already been studying English for seven years.

By 2030, I will already have been studying English for seven years.

Your example includes modal(will), auxiliary(have or have been), and main(studying: present participle of main verb 'study')
So my answer is that they are both correct; though I suggest that the 'already' go to the end of the sentence:

By 2030, I will have been studying English for seven years already.